# moving thread-synchronisation-responisbility into shared resource

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

Given an object(=instance) that is used by multiple threads the following approach is the most common (as far as I know):

the shared resource:

```
class Resource():
    def return_some_value(self):
      return self.somevalue
```

global (or parent context):

```
lock = Lock()
res = Resource()
```

within an accessing thread:

```
lock.acquire()
res.return_some_value()
lock.release()
```

Obviously the accessing thread is responsible to lock and unlock the shared resource.

Lets presume the shared resource is more complex and some methods/properties are read-only while others are not. The Threads using the resource now have to know which is which and lock accordingly. That is obviously error-prone and I sometimes have trouble choosing where to put the Lock object.

Now my question: Is it possible to shift the responsibility to correctly lock to the shared resource itself? Does it even make sense?
Something like:

```
class Resource():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()
    def return_some_value(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        return self.somevalue
        self.lock.release() # obviously this won't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doing that makes perfect sense. You can also [use a `Lock` as a context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement) to ensure it's always released:

```
class Resource():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()

    def return_some_value(self):
        with self.lock:  # Lock gets acquired
            return self.somevalue  # Lock gets released
```

The owner of a `Lock` is based on the thread that acquired it. So many different callers can call into your `Resource` object from different threads, and the lock will behave appropriately.

This wouldn't work well if you need to call multiple methods on `Resource` which require you to hang onto the lock the entire time. In that case, you may want to consider making the resource itself lockable:

```
class Resource():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.lock.acquire()

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.lock.release()

    def return_some_value(self):
        return self.somevalue

    def some_method(self):
        # stuff

    def some_other_method(self):
        # stuff

r = Resource()
with r:
    r.some_method()
    r.some_other_method()
    val = r.return_some_value()
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not sure if the lock would be released after the return statement. But apparently that is always the case with a with-statement (and also with try-finally). I did not know that.

Comment: @Peter Yep, as [stated in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement): "*When a return, break or continue statement is executed in the try suite of a try...finally statement, the finally clause is also executed ‘on the way out.’*"

Comment: In regard to the second part of your answer: If the methods are independent from one an other, both variants would work equally well, wouldn't they?

Comment: @Peter I would say that if each method is independent, the first option is better, since the client doesn't need to worry about locking things at all. If a property/method is read-only for all threads, there's no need to lock them. The only exception to that is if the read-only method is using some resource that can't be shared (like a method that reads from a file object, or uses an iterator, that's stored in the instance, for example). Though I suppose you could argue that's not really "read-only".